# C# deserialization from base type fails trying to convert to derived type

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I have two classes, one being derived from another.
Before creating a `Derived` class, I serialized a `List` of `Base` class objects to a binary file and now I try to deserialize them back, however even if I try assigning the deserialization result to an `object` or not assigning it to anything at all, I get an exception: "Cannot convert type `Base` to type `Derived`" at the line that calls the `Deserialize` method. If I rename the `Derived` class to `Base`, however, it does deserialize, leaving the `Derived` properties that aren't present in `Base` as `null`.

Can I and if I can, how can I have the `BinaryFormatter` not try to convert the `Base` class to `Derived` during deserialization?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of code so we can reproduce the error for ourselves?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've already found the cause of the problem, but thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you want you could [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), then accept the answer.

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I'm pretty new to StackOverflow as a user, so I didn't notice I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.

The `Base` class had a list of class `A` objects, and each of them were referencing the `Base` class at the moment I serialized the `Base` object list. At the moment I tried deserializing it, `A` objects were referencing `Derived` objects in code, but in the file they still referenced `Base`, which caused the conversion error. So the problem was in that I versioned my `Base` objects up to `Derived`, but forgot to version the `A` objects.